# What are the bigquery keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: google-bigquery

Google's bigquery editor has keyboard shortcuts. For example <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> composes a new query. I suspect there are more shortcuts, but I haven't found an useful list of them. Does anyone know them?

Comment: this should be in web applications, not stackoverflow

Answer (score 51):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>: If no query is open: compose new query. If query editor is open: autocomplete current word.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>: Run current query.
- <kbd>Tab</kbd>: Autocomplete current word.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>: Highlight table names.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + click on table name: Open table schema.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd>: Run query from selection.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>: Comment current or selected line(s).
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>: Format query.
  (on Mac, replace <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with <kbd>Cmd</kbd>)

This is the list from the official documentation: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bigquery-web-ui#keyboard_shortcuts

Answer (score 9):

You can see the shortcuts on the UI.

[image]

Comment: it's good that you highlighted the official comments, but the OP listed one that isn't in this list.  You should at least acknowledge that this list is incomplete.

Answer (score 5):

I found myself constantly refreshing bq page by accidentally hitting <kbd>F5</kbd> as it is commonly used shortcut in many data tools for query/script execution. So in recently published Chrome Extension - BigQuery Mate - I have added <kbd>F5</kbd> to execute query while in query editor.

> Just Added:

I realized (a little ago) that one more shortcut is available now that i didn't know or see anyone mentioned before and was not available at a time this question was asked:

While your mouse is over Query Editor - pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> - enters you into mode of copy of any rectangular part of your code. Quite useful!

> July, 7 2016 Refresh:

I thought it also can be helpful to refresh this post with some BgQuery Mate keyboard shortcuts:

- <kbd>F5</kbd> – run query
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>  – run selection
- <kbd>F1</kbd> – help on selected or under-cursor-position keyword/function - opens respective documentation (SQL Version sensitive - Legacy / Standard)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> - comment/uncomment outside selection
  Contextual Menu
- <kbd>Right Click</kbd> > <kbd>BigQuery Mate</kbd> > <kbd>Help</kbd> on selected keyword/function – opens respective documentation (SQL Version sensitive - Legacy / Standard)
- <kbd>Right Click</kbd> > <kbd>BigQuery Mate</kbd> > <kbd>Preserve Format</kbd> anywhere in Editor – Preserve Format – adjust Query Text such that further copy/paste preserves casing

Comment: Not only does Alt let you copy a rectangular section of your editor window, it also lets you  EDIT multiple lines at the same time - just like in IntelliJ, Visual Studio, Atom and other IDEs. Very handy for prefixing comments or removing/adding white space.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know all of them, but this seems a good place to share those I know:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>: runs the query
- <kbd>tab</kbd>: autocomple
- keep <kbd>ctrl</kbd> pressed: highlights the tables, clicking on them takes you to it

(note that in Apple <kbd>ctrl</kbd> might be the <kbd>command</kbd> key - I didn't know about <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>, but it might be overloaded by mac os)

Comment: Ctrl-space also autocompletes when the focus is on the query editor.

Answer (score 2):

Five of the highly used shortcuts for me are the followings:

To select all of the variables with the same name:

First select the variable then
<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

Or

First select the variable then
<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

When you want to select beginning of a series of lines:

Go to the first line, the press

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> +  <kbd>⬆️/⬇️</kbd>

To get recommendation for variables

<kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>esc</kbd> or <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>

depending on your keyboard style.

To duplicate a line of code

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>⬆️/⬇️</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from Felipe Hoffa's answer above, the following keyboard shortcuts work on the Mac:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>: runs the query (same as Windows)
- <kbd>tab</kbd>: autocompletes
- keep the <kbd>command</kbd> key pressed: highlights the tables, clicking on them takes you to it.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, in the new tabbed view UI, there's two new keyboard shortcuts:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>: move line of code up
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>: move line of code down

There might be others. I found them by accidentally hitting these keys. I can't find any documentation on these shortcuts, or I would include it.

Comment: If this is somehow specific to my machine/browser/setup, please let me know.

Comment: If I open a new tab, how do I change the name of it from 'Untitled..' to something meaningful? Nothing seems to work for me.